# Published Ship radio communaction by broadcasting company

Tags: legal, europe

I am unsure if I am in the right department here because it is not amateur radio, but maybe nevertheless somebody can clarify.

Surely everybody has heard about the burning car freighter Freementle Highway off the Dutch Coast. The radio broadcasting company RTL broadcasted radio traffic between captain and coast guard. I searched hard, but I can't find that link any more.

Is that allowed to publish such radio traffic under international or local national (Netherlands) telecom regulations?

Answer (score 1):

The law that would apply depends on the location of whomever was recording. That's the first act that would bear legal scrutiny.

The next act would be sharing that recording with another party (in this case the broadcaster). Again, opportunity for legal scrutiny here, also location of both the sender and recipient will determine what law applies.

Following that, would be the act of re-broadcasting, the communication that was recorded… location of the broadcaster will determine which law applies.

As you're likely aware, radio waves do not respect political boundaries like country borders, so it's not possible to know with precision who actually recorded this (unless they self identify), and they're probably not the only entity to have recorded it.

It's most likely **not illegal** to publish on the Internet or anywhere else recorded radio transmissions of this nature.

This is probably better posted on the law stackexchange: law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Not to mention that national press laws might or might not protect a radio station. Most nations allow, within boundaries, the publication of more or less confidential information through organs of press it a sufficient public interest exists. (Germany is especially strange there, you need printed-on-dead-trees publications to get the same protection as a newspaper. So it might even depend on whether it's Dutch or German RTL...) That's gonna be, at least as far as I imagine, a case-by-case decision of a judge when it comes down to clarifying legality of what a press organ published!

Comment: But I concur, these are not confidential communications to begin with, the whole purpose of that piece of spectrum allocation is communication and documentation in case of an emergency and the public is supposed to be able to at least receive that stuff.

Comment: I hesitate to migrate this to law.SE unless someone gets permission to move it there (ask in their chat).

Comment: Thanks, not that important.